# Why is mustard forbidden on passover?

Tags: passover

I cannot seem to find anything on the matter but have seen entries on multiple Kosher for Passover lists about mustard being forbidden.

Answer (score 3):

[Rama to Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 464:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.464.1?lang=bi):

> והמנהג שלא לאכול חרדל כלל בפסח ... דהוי כמיני קטניות שנוהגין בו איסור:‏
>
> The custom is not to eat mustard at all on Pesach ... because it is like *[kitniyot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitniyot)* (legumes) which we are accustomed to prohibit.

[Mishnah Berurah 464:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.464.5?lang=bi) quotes from Levush that this is because mustard seeds are harvested and gathered like grains.

Comment: [Processed mustard usually also contains non-kosher for pesach vinegar.]

Answer (score 1):

Mustard is not forbidden on Passover. Ashkenazi Jews from Europe have a custom to not eat "kitniyot," which is commonly translated as legumes. And as part of this custom they have decided that mustard is a legume. Therefore it's not actually prohibited, but Kashrut agencies do their best to adhere to the very large Ashkenazi custom of prohibiting kitniyot and so they will often list mustard and other kitniyot products as forbidden.

Jews of Sephardic, Ethiopian, Yemenite, and other Jewish heritages from the middle east all eat mustard on Passover, along with most other types of Kitniyot. So it's important to distinguish what is actually forbidden from "a custom of refraining," because otherwise someone might see a Sephardic Jew eating mustard and think the Sephardic Jew is sinning by eating a prohibited food.

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2179/i-know-a-and-based-on-a-im-asking-b/2182?r=SearchResults#comment8372_2182

Comment: Not everyone agrees with you. KSA for instance writes explicitly (for Ashkenazim) that all types of kitniot are forbidden (117:4) https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.117.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en - a different question is what is included in kitniot

Comment: @mbloch yeah but he also forbids all dried fruits, orange peels, and saffron that you grew inside your garden. No offense but if I asked a question why are dried fruit and fruit peels forbidden in Pesah I think the answer should be they aren't forbidden, just because you have one opunion that says so :p